# Spring OAuth2 token introspection with mTLS

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to implement an OAuth2 resource server using Spring Boot with Spring Security. My introspection server requires mTLS for the token introspection requests.

How can I configure Spring Security to use a client certificate for the token introspection calls?

My security configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyCustomSecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .opaqueToken(opaqueToken -> opaqueToken
                    .introspector(myIntrospector())
                )
            );
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I have tried to provide my own custom introspector which is based upon `NimbusOpaqueTokenIntrospector`, but I can't see any way, how I can add a TLS certificate to the underlaying HTTP request.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? Gotta do the same :)

Comment: @stove Yes, I added my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by using the constructor [NimbusOpaqueTokenIntrospector(String introspectionUri,
org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations restOperations)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/introspection/NimbusOpaqueTokenIntrospector.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations))

As the second constructor argument, I provided a mTLS capable custom implementation of a Spring [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)